# dynamic grouping by in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

i want to make a stored procedure like `makeGroupBy(@a int,@b int,@c int)`. The inputs are 0 or 1 to decide which columns to group by. My attempt so far is below:

```
-- exec makeGroupBy 0,1,0 
-- exec makeGroupBy 0,1,1 
create proc makeGroupBy(@product_id  int = 0,@city_id  int = 1,@date_key  
int = 0) as 
begin
declare @tbl as table(product_id  int, city_id  int, date_key  int, amount                  
float)

insert into @tbl
values(1,1,1,10),
(1,1,1,10),
(1,2,1,5),
(2,2,3,15),
(2,1,3,20),
(3,1,1,25)

select case isnull(@product_id,0) when 0 then 0 else product_id end 
    ,case isnull(@city_id,0) when 0 then 0 else city_id end
    ,case isnull(@date_key,0) when 0 then 0 else date_key end
    , sum(amount) amount from @tbl 
group by case isnull(@product_id,0) when 0 then 0 else product_id end 
    ,case isnull(@city_id,0) when 0 then 0 else city_id end
    ,case isnull(@date_key,0) when 0 then 0 else date_key end
end
```

I don't know if it's possible but what I want is to omit the unwanted columns (inputs with value 0) in the result set.

Comment: You need Dynamic SQL.

Comment: thank you for response. even for this small example i'll need to make 6 different queries for what i want.
imagine the columns quantity is 6.. i'll need to make 63 different queries.

Comment: it always gives me all the three columns but for example for "makeGroupBy 0,1,0 " i dont want product_id and date_key in my resutl set

Comment: @samantarighpeima with `Dynamic sql` you will only have one query. But I think this can be done with `grouping sets()` and `grouping()` or `grouping_id()`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `sql-server` version is greater or equal than `2008`.

```
select 
    product_id
    ,city_id
    ,date_key
    ,sum(amount) as total_amount 
from @tbl
group by grouping sets (
            (product_id, city_id, date_key)
            , (product_id,city_id)
            , (product_id, date_key)
            , (city_id, date_key)
            , (product_id)
            , (city_id)
            , (date_key))
having concat(iif(grouping_id(product_id)=0,1,0),iif(grouping_id(city_id)=0,1,0),iif(grouping_id(date_key)=0,1,0)) = concat(@product_id, @city_id, @date_key) 
order by concat(iif(grouping_id(product_id)=0,1,0),iif(grouping_id(city_id)=0,1,0),iif(grouping_id(date_key)=0,1,0))
```

It seems that a `view` will probably suit best for this case

```
create view [view_name]
as 
select 
    product_id
    ,city_id
    ,date_key
    ,sum(amount) as amount 
    ,concat(iif(grouping_id(product_id)=0,1,0),iif(grouping_id(city_id)=0,1,0),iif(grouping_id(date_key)=0,1,0)) as grp_key
from @tbl
group by grouping sets (
        (product_id, city_id, date_key)
        , (product_id,city_id)
        , (product_id, date_key)
        , (city_id, date_key)
        , (product_id)
        , (city_id)
        , (date_key))
go
```

Then you can query the view like

```
select 
    city_id
    ,date_key
    ,amount
from [view_name]
where grp_key = concat(0,1,1)
```

Comment: still getting all the columns in resultset. but it's another way to do it which i didn't know.. thank you very much.

Comment: @samantarighpeima I recommend you to create a `view` or a `table-valued function` so you can query for the columns you want from the `from` clause. If a `stored procedure` is forced to be used. Then it is more probable than a `Dynamic SQL` have to be used.

Comment: Seems to be a good idea trying to combine your method and dynamic sql and the function. .I'll try to figure it out..thank you it have been helpful

Comment: @samantarighpeima Thanks, It seems a `view` will probably suit best for this case.

Comment: @samantarighpeima it doesn't seem a good idea to combine the two methods. With `Dynamic SQL` specific columns will be grouped, `grouping sets` will group all defined groups of columns and then concatenate the resulting sets. Therefore, I can reasonably suppose `Dynamic SQL` will be more efficient.

Comment: On the other hand, `Dynamic SQL` will have more code and it will be less intuitive to read than a `view` with `grouping sets`. Therefore, I subjectively think that `grouping sets` and a `view` will be more maintainable and intuitive (and probably scalabe to other columns).